# Blazor claims issue transfering var of username

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I need help to pass a var because the username variable can't be road at the `GetAuthenticationStateAsync()`
How can we use for example the code of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0 but making possible the accepting of the reception of a var at `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "mrfibuli")` so like that `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserName)`?
The intellisense dont allow me the creation of the var. The var is `services.AddSingleton<Transaction>();`

Comment: No, the var is not `services.AddSingleton<Transaction>();`. `services.AddSingleton<Transaction>();` is a statement that one expects to see in the setup code for a .net core web app. Then you can receive that singleton via the dependency injection mechanisms provided. It is not clear how all that is related to passing variable content to `new Claim()`. If you have a `string UserName`, of course you can pass it in place of a literal `"mrfibuli"`. How you put the data in that `string UserName` is completely unrelated to where you then pass it.

Comment: it's a cascading parameter `[Parameter] public string UserName { get; set; }` I need to receive it on the class `Dummy.cs`